# create circular text with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want create a Circular Text with JQuery or CSS how can i do that
my goal is somthing like this[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the link Dai provided, but if you'd like a tutorial that goes a bit deeper into the understanding of what makes it work, check this out: http://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/

Here's the associated Codepen link: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/arboK

Answer (score 4):

You could try [circletype.js](http://circletype.labwire.ca/). It's lightweight and works great in fluid layouts.

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 does not support "warped" text-on-a-path such that each character's shape is modified (as in your example), but you can still do regular text-on-a-path.

You don't need any jQuery, static CSS3 will suffice. Use this site here: http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/